# efficient way of calculating shortest path and distance with python's graph-tool

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, graph-tool

I have a dictionary representing origin and destination vertices, for example:

```
{
    0: [1,3],
    1: [0,2],
    2: [1],
    3: [0,1,2],
}
```

The keys represent origin (or source) vertices and the values represent destinations for each origin vertex.
I need to calculate the shortest path and distance between every key and each vertex in the value for that key.

For example, with vertex 3 as the origin, I need to calculate the shortest path and distance between `3->0, 3->1 and 3->2`.

As of now, I'm achieving this with a nested for loop, using graph-tools [shortest_path](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html#graph_tool.topology.shortest_path) and [shortest_distance](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html#graph_tool.topology.shortest_distance) methods, but I believe there must be a more efficient way to achieve this.

I also tried to get the shortest_distance by iterating through the edges returned by `shortest_path`, but while the `shortest_distance` method accepts a list of destinations, the `shortest_path` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. By setting `pred_map=True` in `shortest_distance`, you get a predecessor map that can be used as an argument to `shortest_path`, thus avoiding recomputing the path.